# document.getElementById().style.backgroundImage works with file directory without folder but not with folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I wrote a website last year using raw html, css, and js, but I've been attempting to rebuild my code with react as a good exercise to learn the tool. I've noticed that my old code to reset my backgroundImage no longer works if I use a local image directory within the `url(...)` pointer that contains a step into a folder, and only works with actual http:// urls or ones that do not contain a url; ex. `url('image.png')` or `url('./image.png')`. When the new code runs, the backgroundImage disappears if a local png is being used. I've been scratching my head for some time so I'd appreciate any help.

Old code:

```
function randombg(){
    var random= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    var bigSize = ["url('background-images/1.png')",
                   "url('background-images/2.png')",
                   ...
    document.getElementById("random").style.backgroundImage=bigSize[random];
}
```

CSS:

```
#random {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('assets/background-images/1.png');
    background-repeat: repeat; 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

New code is the same but uses a react function to run the js (handleClick(e) {...}).

Comment: Are you getting 404 in the network for the image resource request? There can be a chance that the local server is not allowing to access the assets directory.  If your local server is running on 3000 port, you can check this by accessing the URL: localhost:3000/assets/background-images/1.png

Maybe you don't need the assets in the URL path.

Comment: @Dipak I've taken a look and I do get a 200 OK on my get request for the image. It seems to work when I'm attempting to access the image without trying to step inside another folder, but when I include a folder in the path it stops working. Ex. 'url("img.png")' works and 'url("./img.png")' works but 'url("./images/img/png")' does not work

Comment: So when you say doesn't work means what's happening? The image is not loading from the server, right (API request for this `url("./images/img/png")` is becoming `404` ) ? What server are you using? Can you create a code sandbox to replicate this scenario?